# Atlassian Bamboo import issue

Tags: bamboo, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am trying to create an hello world task for bamboo by following the instructions mentioned here
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/introduction-to-writing-tasks/

I am facing an error while importing the first library "import com.atlassian.bamboo.build.logger.BuildLogger;"

I've tried searching online for the solution and the majority of such errors require you to externally download the jar file, but I couldn't find the jar as well.

I don't think I will need to download an external jar just to run hello world program, but if that's the case, can you help me find the jar (or maven dependency), else can you guide me on some other way for resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The artifact you're looking for is *atlassian-bamboo-api-6.x.x.jar*, BUT you're supposed to be able to reference it after doing an `atlas-create-bamboo-plugin` at the very beginning (or in step 2 of the tutorial you linked).